# Jquery toggle - Multiple options on the same page

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am having a bit of an issue with multiple toggles on the same page.

Basically I have tables setup to present certain information instantly, a toggle button is included to expand the table to present further information.

I have the toggle working however the issue is with adding additional tables + toggles on the same page were only one will work. I would like each to be independent.

I have had a look at similar scenarios here at sitepoint but I just cant seem to get it to click.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$("#expand").on('click',function(){
    $("[data-rows='togglerow']").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("collapse");

})
});</script>
```

HTML

```
<table id="product-table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" width="100%">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<tbody>
<tr id="tabs">
<td class="tabbg" colspan="2" width="20%">1</td>
<td class="tabbg" width="13%">2</td>
<td class="tabbg" width="12%">3</td>
<td class="tabbg" width="20%">4</td>
<td class="tabbg" width="14%">5</td>
<td class="tabbg" width="11%">6</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prod-info top">
<td class="product-title">1</td>
<td class="expand-more">
    <span id="expand">1</span>
</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>-</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>-</td>
<td>-</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="product-table-bottom" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="prod-info bottom" style="display: none;" data-rows="togglerow">
<td class="product-title">
<a class="button-left">1</a> 
<a class="button-left">2</a> 
<a class="button-left pdf-download" href="#">3</a></td>
<td width="20%"><a class="button-right">4</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thnaks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would need to modify the button so that `expand` is a class.  Only one element on a page should have a certain id, but many elements can have the same class.  You would need a button per table?

With that in mind, the reason it's toggling everything is because your selector is selecting everything, so you will have to modify that slightly to get it to only toggle what you want.

My idea would be to use the `parent()` function a few times until you reach the parent tbody, then find what you need from there.

With all that in mind, this should work for you.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".expand").on('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find("tr [data-rows='togglerow']").toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("collapse");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the help. However I have tried your suggestion and have been unable to get it to work unfortunately.